# Click on submit button not hitting controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Visual Studio 2013.

When I click the submit button, of the form it does nothing.  It does not make the call to the controller action method.

Here is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.propertyID)

    <section id="addRatePeriod">
        <h2>Add a new rate period:</h2>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.StartDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.EndDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.DailyRate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.WeekendDaily)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.Weekly)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.Monthly)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newRatePeriod.MinimumNights)

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Period" id="editSubmit" />
        </div>

    </section>

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index", "", new { @class = "editLink" })

</div>
}
```

Here is the method in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind()]RatePeriodViewModel vm)
    {
        Property property = propertyRepository.GetPropertyByID(vm.propertyID);
        property.ratePeriods.Add (vm.newRatePeriod);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            propertyRepository.UpdateProperty(property);
            propertyRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "RatePeriod", new {id = property.PropertyID });
        }
        return View(property);
    }
```

Everything seems like it should work. I actually copied this code from another one that was working and just changed some things around and now it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Probably you a client validations but are not showing. If you put a `@ValidationSummary(false)`, that might give you a clue

Comment: Add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each of your controls, or remove the `true` parameter from `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

Comment: OK, that did it .  Thanks.  I did not know how the ValidationSummary works.

Comment: can you post your routes?